# How to copy commits to a new branch from master, except specific commits?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a master branch and am trying to copy over commits from the master to a freshly created branch. All commits should be in the new branch except for specific commits.

```
master:    c1-c2-c3-c4-c5-c6-c7-c8-c9
newbranch: c1-c2-c4-c5-c7-c8-c9
```

As above, I would like to copy over all the commits to newbranch except for say, c3 and c6.

Also, I have to keep the master branch unmodified, as it is.

I am using git version 1.8.4

Could you please help me out in this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: google for `cherry-pick`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `cherry-pick` to *copy* commits from a branch to another

Assuming `c1`, `c2` and so on are each commit's sha1 you could do as following

c1-c2-c4-c5-c7-c8-c9

```
git checkout -b newbranch
git cherry-pick c1
git cherry-pick c2
git cherry-pick c4
git cherry-pick c5
git cherry-pick c7
git cherry-pick c8
git cherry-pick c9
```

For this specific case, you might prefer using a GUI interface like SmartGit, which will allow you to cherry-pick each commit selecting it with the mouse, with no need to deal with the SHA1.

Another possibility is to reference commits based on their distance from `master`.

For example, your commit `c9` can be referenced as `master~`, `c8` as `master~2` and so on.

Another possibility is to create a branch at the commit where `master` is

```
git checkout -b newbranch master
```

and then using `git rebase -i` which will create a new branch with only the selected commits

```
git rebase -i HEAD~8
```

An editor will open. Just *pick* the commits you want to retain and discard the one you want to discard, deleting their lines

```
pick 9748201 c2
pick 3b1c9d3 c4
pick 408de72 c5
pick eef6862 c7
pick bffc3a9 c8
pick 669920f c9
```

Then save and, voilà, your `newbranch` will be a copy of `master` without `c3` and `c6`

Comment: nte that `cherry-pick` takes revision-range arguments as well. that merges your 7 commands into 3